# '70s movie, with the tagline "They crushed his face... they changed his voice... but they couldn't keep him from the woman he loved."

Tags: story-identification, movie

Some time in the early to mid '70s, I heard a radio ad for a movie that I presume was either horror or SF. I only remember one line from the ad:

> "They crushed his face... they changed his voice... but they couldn't keep him from the woman he loved."

Comment: it's on topic - the antagonist makes a Faustian deal with the actual devil, and there are some slight sci-fi / futurism elements

Comment: Voted to reopen per [What to do when a vague identification question is off-topic, but the answer is on-topic?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/10533/98028)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Possibly [*Phantom of the Paradise*](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0071994/?ref_=tttg_tg_tt) (1974).

The radio spot you remembered (almost to the word!) would be that one:

> They crushed his face, destroyed his voice, but they couldn't keep him from the woman he loved.

From [RottenTomatoes](https://www.rottentomatoes.com/m/phantom_of_the_paradise/):

> Combining rock & roll, horror, and the classic tale of Phantom of the Opera this musical makes fun of all three. The story centers on an aspiring rocker who sells his soul to find fame and ends up horribly disfigured and living in the bowels of a popular night club.

---

Found with the Google query `taglines "from the woman" site:imdb.com`.

Comment: The timeframe is right, but I don't remember enough to know if this is it. Armed with this title, I'll do some more research. Also:

1. Apparently there's talk of a remake: http://www.sneakpeek.ca/2018/10/phantom-of-paradise.html (I was unaware of this before, I swear!)
2. Directed by Brian DePalma?!?

Comment: @CraigS.Cottingham just as you replied I was including a radio spot. Sounds familiar? :)

Comment: Eerie... that's almost _exactly_ as I remember it, 44 years later. I wish there were a way I could reward your Google-fu more than marking this as the correct answer. :-)

Comment: How/why'd you choose "from the woman" as the main query?  I would have thought it's very broad, and gone with "crushed his face".  Did you try those, to no avail, and the "from the woman" line worked? (Just curious, to help see if there are any insights to help my own Google-fu).

Comment: @CraigS.Cottingham eh, I was helped by your impressive memory. Enjoy the watch! :D

Comment: @BruceWayne I tried `"crushed his face"` and `"changed his voice"` first indeed, but to no avail. Then I went for `"from the woman"` figuring it would surely be broader but at least I'd have some works to browse through. First or second result was it :) *(edited out the part about Google recording my searches because while it's obviously true, I also tried with the wrong keyword so you know... Silly me!)*

Comment: OMG, I **NEED** that movie.